# Reading an ASCII file mixing text and numerics in Mathematica

Tags: import

We have a sequence of large data files ([LAMMPS](http://lammps.sandia.gov/) dump files) which begin like this:

```
ITEM: TIMESTEP
400000
ITEM: NUMBER OF ATOMS
22518
ITEM: BOX BOUNDS pp pp pp
0 527.757
0 532.678
-3.79681 3.79681
ITEM: ATOMS id x y z c_eng 
22248 1.57153 2.05797 0 -0.700402 
8 4.8285 3.9563 0 -0.683748 
22250 5.24995 0.416325 0 -0.559546
```

The file continues for 22515 lines.

In the past we would delete the preamble lines through `ITEM: ATOMS`... and use `ReadList` to harvest the data. Now the file set is too large and we need to automate reading the file, header and all. That is, point to a data file and return numeric values for `TIMESTEP, NUMBER OF ATOMS, BOX BOUNDS`, and an array `{id, x, y, z, energy}`. What is the best use of *Mathematica* for such a case?

Comment: These look like dump files generated by [LAMMPS](http://lammps.sandia.gov/), the molecular dynamics simulator. Is that correct? I just wanted to leave that here in case somebody else searched the site for a similar answer in the future.

Comment: @MarcoB: Good eye, good idea. Yes, a LAMPS output.

Comment: I just tried and think that LAMMPS in a comment is not good enough to find that question when searching for LAMMPS. Why not add it to the title of body text? I don't know if adding a tag is justified, though...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Putting your data in a string stream instead of a real file for this demonstration. With a real file open it using `OpenRead`.

```
file = StringToStream[
   "ITEM: TIMESTEP
   400000
   ITEM: NUMBER OF ATOMS
   22518
   ITEM: BOX BOUNDS pp pp pp
   0 527.757
   0 532.678
   -3.79681 3.79681
   ITEM: ATOMS id x y z c_eng 
   22248 1.57153 2.05797 0 -0.700402 
   8 4.8285 3.9563 0 -0.683748 
   22250 5.24995 0.416325 0 -0.559546 "];
```

Now get the parts of the header you need, skipping over the lines you don't need:

```
Skip[file, String, 1];
timeStep = First@ReadList[file, Number, 1];
Skip[file, String, 1];
numAtoms = First@ReadList[file, Number, 1];
Skip[file, String, 1];
boxBounds = ReadList[file, Table[Number, {6}], 1];
Skip[file, String, 1];
data = ReadList[file, Table[Number, {5}]];
Close[file];
```

Showing that we got the data:

```
{timeStep, numAtoms, boxBounds, data} // Column
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 5):

Here is what I came up with. I am using `Rule` rather than `Set` so the variable names aren't defined as such. But you could definitely adapt your code to do that. I am assuming that the `ITEM:` label is present in all your output files.

```
bits = StringSplit[StringSplit[Import["test.txt"], "ITEM:"], "\n"]

(* {{" TIMESTEP", "400000"}, {" NUMBER OF ATOMS", 
  "22518"}, {" BOX BOUNDS pp pp pp", "0 527.757", "0 532.678", 
  "-3.79681 3.79681"}, {" ATOMS id x y z c_eng ", 
  "22248 1.57153 2.05797 0 -0.700402 ", 
  "8 4.8285 3.9563 0 -0.683748 ", 
  "22250 5.24995 0.416325 0 -0.559546 "}} *)

First[#] -> Map[ToExpression, StringSplit[Rest[#], Whitespace], {2}] & /@ bits

{" TIMESTEP" -> {{400000}}, " NUMBER OF ATOMS" -> {{22518}}, 
 " BOX BOUNDS pp pp pp" -> {{0, 527.757}, {0, 532.678}, {-3.79681, 3.79681}}, 
 " ATOMS id x y z c_eng " -> {{22248, 1.57153, 2.05797, 
0, -0.700402}, {8, 4.8285, 3.9563, 0, -0.683748}, {22250, 5.24995,
 0.416325, 0, -0.559546}}}
```

Further finessing could include using `StringTrim` to clean up the labels and using `Flatten` to make the first two values into a simple number rather than a nested list.